# AppCenter iOS app installation getting error ‘This app can not be installed because of its integrity could not be verified’ on iOS 16

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.forms, ios16

I have developed iOS app using Xamarin Forms.

Every time I install alpha build for iOS app from AppCenter on iPhone 7 (iOS 15.5), iPhone XR (iOS 16.4) and iPhone 12 (iOS 16.5.1).

Now while installing alpha build from AppCenter on iPhone XR and iPhone 12  having  iOS 16.4 and 16.5 respectively,  getting error ‘**This app can not be installed because of its integrity could not be verified**’.

Previously on 13th July, I was able to install same alpha build on same iOS 16.4 version on same iPhone XR.

I am able to install alpha build on iPhone 7 having iOS 15.5.

For alpha, I am using development certificates.

I am trying to find out is there any change in settings for iOS 16.

In some videos it is mentioned to clear Safari or chrome browsing history.
Some videos mentioned Some videos mentioned do not clear browsing history.  If your app is secure then it will ask for access permission while downloading. There is popup to download Configuration profile.
Once you allow this profile, profile will show in Settings-> VPN and Device management
But I am not getting popup to download profile.

Is there any change in settings for iOS 16 while installing app on iPhone?
Any hint for this installation issue on iOS 16?